# React native Cannot pass a read permission (email) to a request for publish authorization

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am implementing fb sdk in react native app. I have done all changes from [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/getting-started), and running in android device. App crashes on Facebook login button click and these are logs.

```
05-23 10:42:20.559 7063-7063/com.fbsample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fbsample, PID: 7063
    Cannot pass a read permission (email) to a request for publish authorization
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.validatePublishPermissions(LoginManager.java:444)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(LoginManager.java:416)
        at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$LoginClickListener.performLogin(LoginButton.java:753)
        at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$LoginClickListener.onClick(LoginButton.java:725)
        at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase$1.onClick(FacebookButtonBase.java:384)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

I searched a lot but none helped me to get rid of this issue.

At least error should contain a suggestion to do.

**I am stuck from hours :/**

There is nothing new from facebook doc.

I have **FBLoginButton.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View } from 'react-native';
    import { LoginButton } from 'react-native-fbsdk';

    export default class FBLoginButton extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <LoginButton
              publishPermissions={["email"]}
              onLoginFinished={
                (error, result) => {
                  if (error) {
                    alert("Login failed with error: " + error.message);
                  } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                    alert("Login was cancelled");
                  } else {
                    alert("Login was successful with permissions: " + result.grantedPermissions)
                  }
                }
              }
              onLogoutFinished={() => alert("User logged out")}/>
          </View>
        );
      }
    };

    module.exports = FBLoginButton;
```

And **App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
var FBLoginButton = require('./FBLoginButton');
const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.label}>Welcome to the Facebook SDK for React Native!</Text>
        <FBLoginButton />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

**Some one tell why this issue persist and what can i do to resolve it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `publishPermissions={["email"]}` to `publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}`, and everything worked.

Comment: you actually allowed all actions from `publish` category. Have you tried `readPermissions={["email"]}` did that work?

Answer (score 5):

you have to change `publishPermissions={["email"]}` to `readPermissions={["email"]}`

Comment: Can you explain `publishPermissions` and `readPermissions` a bit.

Comment: @Khemraj I am doing my first steps in React Native Facebook SDK, so I can't explain much but as I understand you have to use `readPermissions` for `email` as you need it to get information/email. 
And probably you have to use `publishPermissions` to write/publish some information. E.g. for `publish_to_groups` or `publish_pages`...

Answer (score 1):

If you intent to get user's email. You must use `readPermissions={['email']}` on `LoginButton` from `react-native-fbsdk`. Please note if you already built the react native app with `publishPermissions={["email"]}` like in your question, remove the app and then build again.

Also, you can only use either of `readPermissions` or `publishPermissions`, not both. This is by design as documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginButton/#setReadPermissions

If you want to use `readPermissions` and `publishPermissions` on the same app you must invoke the login dialog again. `react-native-fbsdk` provide this with `LoginManager`.

> The LoginManager class is used to request additional permissions for a session or to provide login functionality using a custom UI. Like LoginButton, the LoginManager class is loaded from the react-native-fbsdk module. The example below performs a login with minimal permissions.
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/login